# sed remove digits from end of stirng

Tags: awk, sed, cygwin

remove digits from end of string, example input:

```
example123
example321
example0123
```

expected output:

```
example
example
example
```

I tried the below which didn't work:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' <in.txt >out.txt
```

What should I do?

Comment: What didn't work about it?  Works for me with GNU sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The result of:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' <in.txt
```

Is:

```
example
example
example
```

The command you executed (`sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' <in.txt >out.txt`) will direct the output to the `out.txt` file

Running `cat out.txt` will give you the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`\+` will work on GNU sed, not sure about other implementations. Try this

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]*$//' ip.txt 
example
example
example

$ # or if ERE option is available
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]+$//' ip.txt 
example
example
example
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have whitespace after some of your text.  You don't need the `$` and removing it will solve that problem:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+//' <in.txt >out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the changes directly in the input file, so that you don't have to write another file, then use the '-i' flag:

```sh
sed -i -r 's/[0-9]+$//' in.txt
```