# awk remove lines with digits at end

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to remove lines with digits at the end of the string,

example of input:

```
example123
example
example12
example43
```

expected output:

```
example
```

Comment: Digits or digit? (How many qualify for removal?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed remove digits from end of stirng](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432332/sed-remove-digits-from-end-of-stirng)

Comment: @Kusalananda and those seeing a VTC duplicate to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432332/sed-remove-digits-from-end-of-stirng, it sounds to me like they want to remove/delete lines that end in digits, not "remove just the digits"

Comment: I still want to know how many digits (`s` being used twice in the Q/title) are needed at the end to remove the line; 1, or more?

Answer (score 5):

Very simple to do:

```
awk '/[^0-9]$/ { print }' inputfile
```

Or, if you care to preserve empty lines,

```
awk '! /[0-9]$/ { print }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in case you are interested in `grep` too, following simple `grep` may help also.

```
grep -v '[0-9]$'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed   -e    '/[0-9]$/d'    input-file.txt
```